# "Invalid object name" exception upon seeding an empty database with DbMigrationsConfiguration

Tags: entity-framework

Before database migrations, I was able to use a CreateDatabaseIfNotExists and seed when no database was present. However, I have introduced migrations and, accordingly, have changed my Configuration class to be based on DbMigrationsConfiguration. But with the DbMigrationsConfigurtion, the seed function(s) fail during a context.SaveChanges() with no database:

During startup:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<RegistrationServerContext, Migrations.Configuration>());
RegistrationServerContext db = new RegistrationServerContext();
db.Database.Initialize(true)
```

Models/DbContext:

```
public class RegistrationServerContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ABC> ABCs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<XYZ> XYZs { get; set; }
}
```

Within Configuration:

```
    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Models.RegistrationServerContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(Models.RegistrationServerContext context)
        {
           SeedABCs(context);
           base.Seed(context);
        }

        private void SeedABCs(Models.RegistrationServerContext context)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(..);
            Models.ABC seedABC = new Models.ABC();
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
               var line = reader.ReadLine();
               var values = line.Split(',');
               seedABC.a = values[0];
               seedABC.b = values[1];
               seedABC.c = values[2];
               context.ABCs.Add(seedABC);// <== seedABC is good/valid
               context.SaveChanges();// **<== FAILS HERE**
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So, not being a SQL expert, I now realize that the database hadn't been deleted - used SQL Server's Management Studio to delete the database and seeding now works. As much as Entity Framework shields you from the SQL machinations, it's always good to check with the underlying database technology to confirm operations.